# Can't workout how to get css selectors to scrape in scrapy

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this [website](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) and I am struggling to understand css selectors work with Scrapy.

The css being: https://ibb.co/eJeZpb

Standard css selectors look like:

```
.css-truncate-target .message
.js-navigation-open
time-ago
```

So to make this work in scrapy from there docs it would be:

```
.css-truncate-target .message::text
.js-navigation-open::text
time-ago::text
```

Sorry if this is basic, I'm used to just using standard css selectors.

Code if it helps to see example:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash',
    ]
#.css-truncate-target .message
#.js-navigation-open
#time-ago

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('time-ago.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('.js-navigation-open::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('.js-navigation-open::text').extract_first(),
                "tags": quote.css('time-ago::text').extract(),
            }

# --- run it ---

import scrapy.crawler

c = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'quotes.csv'

})
c.crawl(QuotesSpider)
c.start()
```

My [output](https://pastebin.com/Mkp6KJaF) is if it helps.

Thanks.

I should clarify that I have tried the following also:

```
'text': quote.css('.js-navigation-open::attr(href)').extract_first(),
'author': quote.css('.css-truncate-target .message::attr(href)').extract_first(),
"tags": quote.css('time-ago::text').extract(),
```

Blank csv with: https://pastebin.com/utuZ6u46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your code a little bit with more explicit DOM traversing but the core remained the same.
2 issues I had with your code:

- There is no class `quote` in any `time-ago` tags in the url you provided
- `text` and `author` seem to be extracting text from the same DOM element so I removed the latter

Code:

```
import scrapy.crawler


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('tbody'):
        rows = quote.css('tr')
        for row in rows:
            yield {
                'text': row.css('.js-navigation-open').css('::text').extract_first(),
                "tags": row.css('time-ago').css('::text').extract_first(),
            }


c = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
'FEED_URI': 'quotes.csv'
})
c.crawl(QuotesSpider)
c.start()
```

Result:

> tags,text
>   "Mar 10, 2017",example
>   "Mar 29, 2017",scrapy_splash
>   "Mar 29, 2017",tests
>   "Mar 30, 2016",.coveragerc
>   "Apr 19, 2016",.gitignore
>   "Mar 10, 2017",.travis.yml
>   "Mar 29, 2017",CHANGES.rst
>   "Apr 11, 2016",LICENSE.txt
>   "Feb 27, 2015",MANIFEST.in
>   "Jul 14, 2016",README.rst
>   "Apr 16, 2016",pytest.ini
>   "Mar 25, 2016",requirements-py3.txt
>   "Feb 15, 2016",requirements.txt
>   "Feb 27, 2015",setup.cfg
>   "Mar 29, 2017",setup.py
>   "Mar 10, 2017",tox.ini